# Diff between two date (String)

Tags: php

**FIRST QUESTION :**

I have a little problem.

I would like to know the difference between two dates (number of hours) that I receive in String format

Except I have a mistake:

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function diff() on bool in C:\xampp\htdocs\simu_boitier\modeles\dao\tarifDAO.php:15 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\simu_boitier\controleurs\controleurSimulateurTarif.php(60): tarifDAO::calculMontant('M', '2021-01-21T09:2...', '2021-01-21T13:2...', 'Clas', '500') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\simu_boitier\controleurs\controleurPrincipal.php(22): include_once('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\simu_boitier\index.php(14): include_once('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #3 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\simu_boitier\modeles\dao\tarifDAO.php on line 15

```
public static function calculMontant($categ_voiture, $dateDebut, $dateFin, $formuleAbonnement, $distanceKM) {

        echo ($dateDebut);
        echo($dateFin);

        $test = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d h:i:s', $dateDebut);
        $testdate = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d h:i:s', $dateFin);

        $duree = $test->diff($testdate);
        echo $duree->format('%h hours');

    }
```

echo returns :

2021-01-21T09:24

2021-01-21T13:24

Thank you

**EDIT SOLVE :**

```
    public static function calculMontant($categ_voiture, $dateDebut, $dateFin, $formuleAbonnement, $distanceKM) {

        $dateDebut = str_replace('T', ' ', $dateDebut);
        $dateFin = str_replace('T', ' ', $dateFin);

        $test = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d h:i', $dateDebut);
        $testdate = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d h:i', $dateFin);

        $duree = $test->diff($testdate);
        echo "test";
        echo $duree->format('%H hours');

        //$tarif_horaire = self::recupTarifHoraire($categ_voiture, $duree, $formuleAbonnement);
        $tarif_km = self::recupTarifKM($categ_voiture, $distanceKM, $formuleAbonnement);

        //$tarif_totale = $tarif_horaire*$duree;
        //$tarif_totale =$tarif_totale + $tarif_km*$distanceKM;

        $tarif_totale = $tarif_km*$distanceKM;

        return $tarif_totale;


    }
```

**SECOND QUESTION :**
If the "duree" value is equal or greater than 24 the function bugs.
No error messages but my echo do not display anything.

I would like for example if there is 1 week between the two dates that they return the total number of hours (168)

Thanks

Comment: The error message means, that your attempt to parse the date in the specified format failed. And of course it did, because `2021-01-21T09:24` does _not_ match `Y-m-d h:i:s` - it does not match the literal `T` character, and there is not seconds part in your input value either.

Comment: Also you need `H` instead of `h` as your hours are in 24-hr format. Read https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php **carefully**.

Comment: Thanks for awnser CBroe,
How could I do to be able to convert my String to date in this format there because I receive this value from an <input type='datetime-local'>

EDIT : I just thought about it and I could replace the T with a space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works :

```
public static function calculMontant($categ_voiture, $dateDebut, $dateFin, $formuleAbonnement, $distanceKM) {

        $date1 = new DateTime($dateDebut);
        $date2 = new DateTime($dateFin);

        $diff = $date2->diff($date1);

        $hours = $diff->h;
        $hours = $hours + ($diff->days*24);

        echo "nbheure : ", $hours;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the [Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) date component...

```php
$diff = Carbon\Carbon::parse($date)->diffForHumans(Carbon\Carbon::now());


echo $diff; //before 24 days
```